# Using MediaRecorder object in Angular/Electron application

Tags: angular, typescript, types, electron, mediacapture

I'm trying to use a MediaRecorder object, but the compiler doesn't recognize it.

```
startStreaming(){
 const mediaStream=this.canvas.captureStream(30);
 this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream, {
  mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=h264',
  videoBitsPerSecond : 3 * 1024 * 1024
 });
 this.mediaRecorder.start(1000);
}
```

`this.canvas` has been declared as a `HTMLCanvasElement`, but still I have this error on `captureStream`:
`Property 'captureStream' does not exist on type 'HTMLCanvasElement'.`

On the following line, I have `Cannot find name 'MediaRecorder'.`

Till now, I tried to:

1. install dom-mediacapture-record: `npm install -d @types/dom-mediacapture-record`
2. add 'dom-mediacapture-record' to `types` in `tsconfig.json`

But nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding 'dom-mediacapture-record' to the `types` array in your `tsconfig.app.json` instead of the `tsconfig.json`?
This worked for me.